# Вывод текста который находится в div js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу вывести текст который находиться только в `<div>` а именно `asd`

```js
$("#text").click(function() {
  var text = $("#text").text();
  console.log(text);
})
```

```css
#text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#text span {
  background: red;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="false">Текст</span>
asd</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - это создать клон объекта, удалить всех детей и получить `textContent`

```js
let txt = jQuery("#text").clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
console.log(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"><span contenteditable="false">Текст</span>
asd</div>
```